# Letsencrypt SSL Certifcate with Same Public Key?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

As Letsencrypt SSL certificates renew every 90 days, I would like to keep same public key even after renewal. Is it possible, if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here - https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/prevent-public-key-changin-when-renewing-ssl-certs/25489/6

As of now we can use clients other than cert-bot to renew certificates by keeping same public key.